# Change CSS properties via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, background-attachment

I need to modify some CSS properties via JavaScript.
The website I need to work with is based on a CMS and I can only edit body elements to inject code.

I was wondering if there was a way to use JavaScript to modify/override the CSS on-the-fly as the page loads?

At the present time I am looking to modify two properties (but maybe more in the future):

```
background-image:url(http://mysite.com/img/bg.jpg);
background-attachment: scroll;
```

I would like them to be changed to the following on the specific page I intend to embed this script on:

```
background-image:url(http://mysite.com/img/new_bg.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I tried this, but it did not work (remember I can only put this within the body of the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://mysite.com/img/new_bg.jpg)';
</script>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750710/setting-background-image-with-javascript

Comment: I want to do this with pure JavaScript. The link you shared is using JQuery.

Answer (score 5):

`document.getElementById` takes an element ID.

Unless you have an element with `id="body"`, your code won't find any element.

You probably want `document.body`, which always returns the one and only `<body>` element.