# How to send parameters from javascript to css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parameters

I want to set the background image based on user selection.

Scenario:

User selects a color among color options. Based on this the background image must be changed like theme.

For example, if user selects red color background image should be image_red.png. If user changes the color to violet it should be image_violet.png.

There are multiple images like this the color of which should change according to user selection. So is there a way of setting it in css like background-image: url(../image_colorparameter.png)

Comment: Please see this article .This got what you want 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195303/set-css-attribute-in-javascript

Comment: Please see this article .This got what you want 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195303/set-css-attribute-in-javascript

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750710/setting-background-image-with-javascript

Comment: if u just want to use change color of you can use background-color instead of using an image

Comment: the simple way: set a class or data-attrib on the body with the value of the user-selected color. then you can use pure css attrib selectors to change all sorts of rules by prefixing the normal selector with a, ex, "body[data-color='red'] " limiter. having just one line of JS simplifies coding while separating boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

## Specific Classes

So, here's a nice way to do it if you have specific `classes` in mind:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/nbMdb/

**(added background functionality for class names)**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/nbMdb/2/

**(additional proof of concept. Type your own dynamic image and it will populate.)**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/nbMdb/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="thisThing"></div>

<input id="yellow" type="button" name="yellow" value="yellow" />
<input id="red" type="button" name="red" value="red" />
<input id="blue" type="button" name="blue" value="blue" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#thisThing {

    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.yellow {
    background:#FC2;
}
.blue {
    background:#00F;
}
.red {
    background:#F00;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('input').on('click', function() {
        var color = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#thisThing').removeClass();
        $('#thisThing').addClass(color);
    });
});
```

**Obviously you'd change the classes from `background` to `background:url(...)` but I didn't have your images.**

**Additional note. No need to use `ID` if you don't want. `value`, `name` also work in this case. See here:**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/nbMdb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS properties using $.css() method. http://api.jquery.com/css/
Also you can retrieve the CSS property using the same method.

Following method will allow you to change the background image in a parametrized way based on user selection.

```
function changebackground(var color) {
   $('body').css('background-image','url(img/'+ color +'.jpg)');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of simple way is to just assign image name as an id for option. Once any option is selected do ::
var v = $("option").id();
$("body").css("background","url("+v+")");